# Which database support scalability and availability?

Tags: database

What database software can do these?

- Scalability via data partitioning, such as [consistent hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing).
- Redundancy for fail over.  Both memory cache and disk storage together.  Key-value data. Value is document type such as JSON.
- Prefers A and P in [CAP theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).

I heard that [MemcacheD](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiW2szOiIvMAhVJzWMKHQNiADkQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmemcached.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNE-sTYE_70SrRfg9z8bVDUw_u7Ldg&sig2=P5cWJa1obTUfogUeCKChdg&cad=rjt) can do these all, but I am not sure.

Here's details:

- Data storage volume is, <30KB JSON document for each key. Keys shall be >100,000,000.
- Data is accessed >10K times for a second.
- Persistence is needed for every key-value data.
- No need for transaction.
- Development environment is C#, but other languages are ok if the protocol spec is known.
- Map reduce is not needed.

Comment: Possibly better suited to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. I want to move this question to there. How can I do it? Delete then copy?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too short a spec description to choose a database. There are tons of other contraints to consider (data storage volume, data transfer volume, persistence requirement, needs for transactions, development environnment, map reduce, etc.).

That being said:

- `Memcached`or `Redis` are *memory database* which means that you cannot store more than what your computer memory can hold. This is less true now that distributed capabilities have been added to redis.
- Document database (such as `MongoDB` or `Microsoft Document Db`) support everything. And you can add `memcached` or `redis` in front. That's how most people use them.
- I would like to add that any SQL can now deal with JSON. So that works too. With a cache up front if needed.

Some [link of interest](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Hadoop-Big-Data-Cassandra-MongoDB-CouchDB) for JSON oriented database. But once again. That's too short a spec to choose a database.

Comment: I am sorry. Data storage volume is, <30KB JSON document for each key. Keys shall be >100,000,000. Data is accessed >10K times for a second. Persistence is needed for every key-value data. No need for transaction. Development environment is C#, but other languages are ok if the protocol spec is known. Map reduce is not needed.